# Repeated logs "client closed connection while SSL handshaking"

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kong

I see some strange logs in my kong container, which internally uses nginx:

```
2019/08/07 15:54:18 [info] 32#0: *96775 client closed connection while SSL handshaking, client: 10.244.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0:8443
```

This happens every 5 secs, like some sort of diagnostic is on.
In my kubernetes descriptor I set no ready or liveliness probe, so I can't understand why there  are those calls and how can I prevent them from appearing as they only dirt my logs...

**edit**: 
It seems it's the LoadBalancer service: I tried deleting it and I get no logs anymore...how to get rid of those logs though?

Answer (score 2):

This has been already discussed on Kong forum in [Stopping logs generated by the AWS ELB health check](https://discuss.konghq.com/t/stopping-logs-generated-by-the-aws-elb-health-check/3752) thread.
The same behaviour with lb heathcheck every few seconds.

> Make Kong listen on plain HTTP port, open that port up only to the
> subnet in which ELB is running (public most probably), and then don’t
> open up port 80 on the ELB. So ELB will be able to Talk on port 80 for
> health-check but there won’t be a HTTP port available to external
> world.
>
> Use L4 proxying (stream_listen) in kong, open up the port and
> then make ELB healthcheck that port.

Both of solutions are reasonable.

Comment: Kong has both http and https ports open, how can I change the default loadbalancer configuration so that it performs healthcheck on http?

Answer (score 0):

Just simply check what is connecting to your nginx:

```
kubectl get po,svc --all-namespaces -owide | grep 10.244.0.1
```

after that, you should know what is happening inside your cluster, maybe a misconfigured pod or some clients.

Comment: Ok ghosts are real...no entry has that IP, but it still in my log and keeps opening SSL connections

Comment: Did you check services too?

Comment: Yep, anyways now I'm 100% sure it's the load balancer: I created another pod with the same image and I get no strange logs. It's obvious that the load balancer is trying to connect to my pod every 5 sec to make sure it's alive..

Comment: Please update if you find a solution because nothing better than changing log level doesn't come to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this error when watching the log of Nginx.
I use the Azure cloud, I found the **ip** in the log is the location of my Azure server

I resolved that by changing the **Protocol** option from [TCP] to [**HTTPS**] in **Heath probes** menu on *Azure portal*